# Selenium Webdriver - Element not visible

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium webdriver. I am trying to do registration for `http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/index.php`.

I am able to switch to pop up and able to fill all field values. But when I try to click on <kbd>SUBMIT</kbd> button it shows exception `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible`

I have used Xpath with below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='load_form']/div/div[2]/input")).click();
```

HTML is:

```
<div class="span_1_of_4" align="center">
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you share how you switched to that popup? I've asked it in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41828847/python-selenium-webdriver-cannot-switch-to-registration-pop-up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I see in your provided website [url](http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/index.php) there are two `Submit` buttons are present, so when you are using xPath `.//*[@id='load_form']/div/div[2]/input` it returns two submit button and it goes to click on first `Submit` button which is not visible on the form, So you should try as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#load_box input.button")).click();
```

Hope it will work..:)

Answer (score 2):

The following approach worked successfully for me:

```
WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#load_box input.button")));
WebDriverwait wb= new WebDriverwait(20,driver)l
wb.until(ExpectedConditions.ElementVisible(ele)));
ele.click();
```