# Python - selenium webdriver - cannot switch to registration pop-up

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, popup, alert

I am new to python (2.7) & selenium webdriver. 
And I am trying to do registration for http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/index.php

So far i got stuck at switching to the registration pop-up.

I've tried

```
driver.get("http://www.way2automation.com/demo.html")
regElem = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Registration").click()

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("login"))

nameElem = driver.find_element_by_name("name").clear()
nameElem.send_keys("NameBla")
```

In the place where i try to switch to the pop-up i've checked different xpathes & different methods `switch_to_frame / switch_to_window / alert / etc`. But no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually no `iframes` that you need to handle. Target `fieldset` located in a simple `div`, so you need just to wait for its presence

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.way2automation.com/demo.html")
current = driver.current_window_handle
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Registration").click()
new =  [window for window in driver.window_handles if window != current][0]
driver.switch_to_window(new)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
nameElem = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,'name')))
nameElem.send_keys("NameBla")
```

without switching to `frame / switch_to_window / alert / etc`

Comment: If I 'just' run without switching I get selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"name"}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320958/selenium-webdriver-element-not-visible user says "I am able to switch to pop up and able to fill all field values", so I assume there should be some kind of switching

Comment: Thanks @Andersson, but I've tried your variant with waits and got selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:  So the elements are just never found this way

Comment: No, there is no need to switch to somewhere. Try to replace `presence_of_element_located` with `element_to_be_clickable` as in updated answer. This code works

Comment: For me it still throws TimeoutException

Comment: Sorry :) You didn't mentioned that you use `Chrome`. I tried it in `Firefox` and there was no need to switch as no new windows opens... Now I updated my answer for `Chrome`

Comment: That does the trick! Sorry, i didn't expect the browser-dependency to be that drastic!)