# How to switch to frame if you can't find iframe tag in html

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape:

https://shop.mango.com/us/women/jackets-biker-jackets/leather-biker-jacket_53095011.html?c=CG&n=1&s=prendas_she.familia;16,304

Click on discover my size and then I have to put values in the input fields. However, I am not really sure how to switch to this frame to perform further actions since I can't find relevant iframe tag

Comment: There is no `<iframe>`

Comment: I know. How do I shift to it? the pop up @Guy

Comment: You don't. Just wait for the fields to be visible.

Comment: Anybody looking for answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41828847/python-selenium-webdriver-cannot-switch-to-registration-pop-up